# Javascript confirm method not working

Tags: javascript, asp.net, gridview

I have a button for delete record in a asp.net grid view

```
<asp:Button ID="btnDelete" CssClass="btn btn-Delete" ToolTip="delete" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("IDJob")%>' UseSubmitBehavior="false" OnClientClick="return confirm('are you sure?')" />
```

when click on it `RowCommand` does not fire. if remove the `OnClientClick` it works.

Can anyone help me please.

Comment: you should use `onclick` instead of `OnClientClick`

Comment: I believe you have another js click handler which occurs before and returns `true`. That's why your handler is ignored

Comment: when use onclick   instead of OnClientClick :  Identifier expected; 'return' is a keyword

Comment: OnClick is for connecting .NET event handlers. OnClientClick is for JS handlers, so it is the correct one to use here. See This is an ASP.NET control, not a HTML tag. OnClientClick is the correct way. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.onclientclick%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in place of onClientclick use onclick. onclick will execute a JavaScript when a button is clicked.

```
<asp:Button ID="btnDelete" CssClass="btn btn-Delete" ToolTip="delete" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("IDJob")%>' UseSubmitBehavior="false" Onclick="return confirm('are you sure?')" />
```

Comment: when use onclick instead of OnClientClick : Identifier expected; 'return' is a keyword

Comment: why you are using return here?

Comment: but if I don't use return at here it doesn't differen that cancel or click on ok, both of then has one result.

Comment: i am not sure where you will check return result but in that case you can use some javascript function name and there you can check result  something like this:        function ab(){if (confirm('are you sure')){
  //do something
}else{
   alert("something else")
}}

Comment: and use call  function on Onclick="ab();"

Comment: This is an ASP.NET control, not a HTML tag. OnClientClick is the correct way. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.onclientclick%28v=vs.110%29.aspx